# Passing a react-native useState argument to a component within jest testing environment

Tags: typescript, react-native, testing, jestjs

I have a modal that takes in an useState argument that is used to show or close the modal based on a button click. (close button is in the modal and show button is in a separate functional component).

When I try to use useState in jest I get the following error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component
```

This is how my modal is defined:

```
export default function PDFViewer({modalVisible, setModalVisible, file, filename}: {modalVisible:boolean, setModalVisible:Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>, file:string, filename?:string }): JSX.Element { ... Modal code ...}
```

Instead of using use state I am passing in a void function right now but that isn't very useful.

jest render:

```
        const { getByText} = render(
            <AuthProvider>
                <PDFViewer modalVisible={false} setModalVisible={function (value: React.SetStateAction<boolean>): void {
                    throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
                } } file={""} />
            </AuthProvider>
        );
```

What is the best way to actually pass in a useState to the modal?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm facing a similar challenge and would love to know how to solve it.